# Inspecting a peculiar sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the following double sequence $A:\Bbb N^2\to \Bbb R$

$$A_{n,m}=\cases {1 & if $m = 0$\\
\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{A_{k,m-1}}} & if $m > 0$}$$

Notice that $A_{n,0}$ is the sequence of 1s, $A_{n,1}$ is the sequence of natural numbers, and $A_{n,2}$ is the sequence of harmonic numbers. None of these three sequences have an interesting limit as $n\to\infty$ (it appears all $m$ but $m = 0$ have a limit of $\infty$).

What might be interesting, on the other hand, is the limit as $m\to\infty$. Consider $A_{2,m}$:

$$\begin{array}{cc}m&A_{2,m}\\0&1\\1&2\\2&1.5\\3&1.6666666666666665\\4&1.6\\5&1.625\\6&1.6153846153846154\\7&1.619047619047619\\8&1.6176470588235294\\9&1.6181818181818182\\10&1.6179775280898876\\11&1.6180555555555556\\12&1.6180257510729614\\13&1.6180371352785146\\14&1.6180327868852458\\15&1.618034447821682\end{array}$$

I find this interesting because it seems that $\min\{A_{2,m-2}, A_{2,m-1}\} < A_{2,m} < \max\{A_{2,m-2}, A_{2,m-1}\}$ and it also seems that this sequence approaches the golden ratio.

So let us now construct a new sequence:

$$ x_n = \lim_{m\to\infty}{A_{n,m}}$$

**Assorted questions:**

1. Is $x_n$ a well known sequence?
2. Are any items in the sequence "famous" other than $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = \phi$?
3. Proof that $x_2$ is indeed the golden ratio
4. Can $x_n$ be expressed in some other, nicer form?

Any and all information about this sequence would be appreciated. My computer is about to explode from the testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These limits $x_n$ can all be evaluated. Clearly $x_1=1$. Since $A_{2,m} = 1/1 + 1/A_{2,m-1}$, the positive limit $x_2$ must satisfy $x_2 = 1 + 1/x_2$; the positive solution of this equation (quadratic, once we multiply through by $x_2$) is the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt5)/2$.

Continuing, we have $A_{3,m} = 1/1 + 1/A_{2,m-1} + 1/A_{3,m-1}$; if the limit $x_3$ exists, then it must satisfy $x_3 = 1 + 1/x_2 + 1/x_3$, which (since we know the value $x_2=\phi$) is a quadratic equation in $x_3$. Its positive solution is
$$
\frac{3+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2 (19+7 \sqrt{5})}}{2+2 \sqrt{5}} \approx 2.09529,
$$
which is the largest of four real roots of the polynomial $x^4-x^3-3 x^2+x+1$.

In general, $x_n$ must be the positive root of the quadratic equation $x_n = S_{n-1} + 1/x_n$, where $S_n = 1 + 1/x_2 + \cdots + 1/x_{n-1}$; that is, we get the recursive formula
$$
x_n = \frac{1}{2} \big(\sqrt{S_{n-1}^2+2S_{n-1}+5}+S_{n-1}+1\big),
$$
showing that $x_n$ is some algebraic number of degree (at most) $2^{n-1}$.

Numerically, it seems that $x_n \sim \sqrt{2n}$ as $n\to\infty$; this probably isn't too hard to prove, but I haven't tried to prove it.

Comment: Thank you! I had forgot about that method for evaluating the limit of an iterative sequence.